# pyqgis add a picture

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, print-composer

I am looking for a way to add a picture to my map using pyqgis. Are there any examples of how to do this. I know it can be done using the classQgsComposerPicture. I am not much of a programmer so I cannot decode the api documentation. Any links where I can find such examples or documentation with options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I want to add an icon QGIS logo (111 pixels x 111 pixels) to my composer map, the snipped code that it works is:

```
.
.
.

#Initialize the picture object
logo = QgsComposerPicture(c) #c is a QgsComposition object
logo.setPictureFile("/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/qgis-icon_21.png")
logo.setSceneRect(QRectF(0,0,40,40)) #Resize logo
logo. setItemPosition(20,20)
c.addItem(logo)
.
.
.
```

The result is:

[image]

With this **QRectF(0,0,20,20)** object I have:

[image]

I have to use the 'setSceneRect' method of **QgsComposerPicture** class.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing other examples from the [PyQGIS cookbook](http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/composer.html) , the following should work

```
image = QgsComposerPicture(c)
image.setItemPosition(x, y)
image.setPicturePath('/path/to/image')
image.updateItem()
c.addItem(image)
```